# Every $\epsilon$-neighborhood of a point in a closed ball contains a second point of the ball

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $E$ be a closed ball with centre at $0$ and radius $1$ at $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $z\in E$. Prove that for any $\varepsilon>0$ neigborhood $N_{\varepsilon}(z)$ has point $x\neq z$ such that $x\in E$

How to prove this fact strictly?

Comment: Take $x := z - \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\frac{z}{\| z \|}$.

Comment: I must show that $\rho(x,0)\leqslant 1$ and $\rho(x,z)<\varepsilon$? Am i right?

Comment: I assumed that you are talking about the Euclidean metric $\rho$. Right; you have to examine those two.

Comment: $\rho(x,0)=|x|=|z-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\frac{z}{\| z \|}=|\| z \|-\varepsilon/2|$ How to prove that last is less than $1$

Comment: Recall that $\| \lambda z \| = \lvert \lambda \rvert \| z \|$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\| z \| \leq 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Orat has given an explicit construction which works in his comment, but it may also be helpful to understand why such a construction is used, along with how you can find similar constructions to solve related problems.

To prove this constructively from first principles, given an arbitrary $x \in E$ and $\varepsilon>0,$ we wish to find a $z$ that satisfies the given properties (and prove that it works).

Here drawing a picture can be useful to find a general construction - this also applies for more complicated examples. In particular, doing this you will realise that all points on the line segment between $0$ to $x$ is in $E.$ More precisely, for any $\lambda \in [0,1],$

$$ z = \lambda 0 + (1-\lambda)x = (1-\lambda x) \in E $$

Now we want to choose $\lambda$ s.t. $d(x,z)<\varepsilon.$  Here we can expand out the definitions and proceed algebraically (setting $d(x,z)=\varepsilon/2$ helps simplify things), though you can also find a working value through geometric means.

Answer (score 0):

If not, $z$ is an interior ponit of $E^{c}$. So it is contradict to $z\in E$.

Comment: Can you explain this in details?

Comment: Let $A$ be a Set of interior points of $E^{c}$. It is a subset of $E^{c}$. So, $z\in A\subsset E^{c}$

Comment: If not, $z$ would be an isolated point of $E$, not an interior point of $E^c$. The point is to show that the ball has no isolated points.